# ROS moveit programmatically adding collision object

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-groovy, collision-object

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to add Collision objects to the planning scene, similar to how it was previously possible in Electric+arm_navigation (see [code](http://answers.ros.org/question/11408/ros-electric-arm-navigation-programmatically-adding-collision-object/) ). However, I did not get the code to work because the headers are deprecated in Groovy and MoveIt. Does anyone have an idea how to do a similar thing in Groovy+MoveIt?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56466/ros-moveit-programmatically-adding-collision-object/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late reply, but here it is:

You can do this in two ways: either you publish a CollisionObject message on the /collision_object topic, or, you can call
processCollisionObjectMsg() function directly on the PlanningScene, if you are in the same process.
Furthermore, you can do something like:
planning_scene->getWorld()->addToObject("object_name", Shape, Pose);

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on 2013-04-15**:
Thanks for your comment isucan. I would like to add a cylinder (shape primitive) as collision object, but I am struggling to write a cpp file similar to the tutorial 'Adding known objects to the collision environment'. As far as I know, such an example does not exist for MoveIt, or do I miss somethi

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Very late reply, but I just created an easy helper function to publish a collision cylinder
https://github.com/davetcoleman/moveit_visual_tools

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2014-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1